# Why does Make skip the prerequisite once the target file is generated?

Tags: makefile, prerequisites

I don't understand that once the target file - $(TEST_LOG) has been generated, both make check_tests and make eval_test will skip the prerequisite but execute the recipe. Can someone give some guidance and help me to understand it?

Let's say, $(TEST_LOG) was generated one day ago, comparing with current timestamp, it is out-dated.
Then user do make eval_test now,  it should remake test.log within current timestamp. But in this case, the target $(TEST_LOG) is skipped. But it do execute the rule. In my opinion, if make skip the prerequisite, it will skip to execute recipe as well. Why does make act in this way in this case?

```
TEST_LOG = test.log

check_tests: $(TEST_LOG) eval_test


$(TEST_LOG):
    @echo "-- ERROR --" |& tee -a $@

eval_test: $(TEST_LOG)
    @if [ `grep -cs "ERROR" $(TEST_LOG)` -eq 0 ]; then exit 0; else exit 1 ; fi
```

Thanks,
TM

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. *"Let's say, $(TEST_LOG) was generated one day ago, comparing with current timestamp, it is out-dated."* By that reasoning, every file is always out-dated. Make has no way of knowing that you want to refresh that file every day, or every hour, or whatever you have in mind. What *do* you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, and I realize that something in my mind needs to be correct about the out-dated judgement. The most challenge for me to get there is why $(TEST_LOG) is skipped but execute the recipe. Is it a common case for make?

Comment: Out-of-date means that something has a prerequisite which has been changed (or more precisely, *updated)* since the thing was built. That's what prerequisites are for. `$(TEST_LOG)` has no prerequisites, therefore if it exists, it is up-to-date and need not be rebuilt. It is a very common case for Make.

Comment: OK. Sounds reasonable. If prerequisite has been changed, then execute the recipe. By that reasoning, how does make eval_test execute recipe but $(TEST_LOG) is up-to-dated?

Comment: Because there is no file named `eval_test`, so it can never be up to date.  If you created a file named `eval_test`, then the target would be up to date.  On the other hand, there is a file named `test.log`, and so that file is always up to date, since it has no prerequisites.  If there are no prerequisites then "does the file exist" is the only way to determine if it's up to date.

Answer (score 0):

If you want Make to rebuild `test.log` every time you call `make test.log` or `make eval_test`, you can add one line to the makefile:

```
TEST_LOG = test.log

.PHONY: $(TEST_LOG)
```

This tells Make that `test.log` is not to be considered a file name, and therefore that if it is called for (as a prerequisite) the rule must be executed, regardless of what files exist.

(The `PHONY` line can be almost anywhere in the makefile, as long as it is after the definition of `TEST_LOG`, and not in a rule.)